# Quick probability question (multiplication of expectations)

Tags: probability

Is $E[(X-E[X])U] = E[U]E[X-E[X]]$ for RV $U,X$: U mean independent of X? If so, why? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "U mean independent of $X$"?

Comment: It's just E[U|X] = 0

Comment: Don't you mean $E[U|X] = E[U]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This holds for all $X, U$:

$$E[(X-E[X])U] = E[XU] - E[X]E[U] = Cov(X,U)$$

You are telling us that the first expression equals:

$$E[U]E[X-E[X]] = E[U](E[X] - E[E[X]]) = E[U] \cdot 0 = 0$$

So this means that the $Cov(X,U)$ is $0$. However that doesn't imply $X$ independent of $U$, because [uncorrelatedness does not imply independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Uncorrelatedness_and_independence).